# Why is `var objCArray = array as NSArray` legal?

Tags: swift

It's easy to cast between Swift arrays and NSArrays. I found a case that I don't think should compile:

```
let doubleArray = [1.1, 2.22, 3.333, 4.4444, 5.55555, 
  6.666666, 7.7777777, 8.88888888, 9.999999999]

var objCArray = doubleArray as NSArray
```

The second line creates an NSArray from my Swift array of doubles, but it stores it in a `var`. This test the compiler that it's legal to change the contents of the array. That means that if you try to then mutate the array, you get an error, even though objCArray is declared as a `var`:

```
objCArray[0] = 123
```

Why is the line `var objCArray = doubleArray as NSArray` legal?

Comment: `var objCArray` just means that you can assign something else to it later, e.g. `var objCArray = someOtherDoubleArray as NSArray`

Comment: And why should it be illegal? `var objCArray` defines a mutable pointer, one that you can change the address it's holding. Whether the object it's pointing to is mutable or not is a different matter

Answer (score 5):

```
let doubleArray = [1.1, 2.22, 3.333, 4.4444, 5.55555, 6.666666, 7.7777777, 8.88888888, 9.999999999]
var objCArray = doubleArray as NSArray
```

> Why is the line var objCArray = doubleArray as NSArray legal

Because, like every other `var` declaration, it allows you to replace the value of the variable. In this case, you would be allowed to replace the NSArray at `objCArray` with a *different* NSArray:

```
objCArray = [2.9]
```

Nevertheless, NSArray itself is immutable. That's just a fact about this Objective-C class. So, for example, you cannot assign to `objCArray[0]`. That has nothing to do with `let` vs. `var` here; it's a fact about what an NSArray itself is:

```
 objCArray[0] = 123 // error
```

Now, you might say: that's totally different from how Swift structs work. Very true! But NSArray is *not* a Swift struct. It's not Swift, and it's not a struct. It's an Objective-C class! Swift Array is a Swift struct, and you should use it instead.

---

**Further discussion**: The question, as it stands, is patently absurd, and we can see this even by concentrating solely on Swift structs:

- You are allowed to assign to a `var` property of a struct in Swift *only* if the struct reference itself is declared with `var`.
- You are *not* allowed to assign to a `let` property of a struct in Swift, *even* if the struct reference itself is declared with `var`.
- But that does not mean that, just because a struct has only `let` properties, it cannot be declared with `var`! That would be absurd. Yet that absurdity is exactly the same as the absurdity in your question.

  ```
  struct S {
      let name = "Matt"
  }
  var s = S() // should this be illegal...
  // ... just because assigning to S.name is illegal???
  ```

Comment: What if we changed that line to `var objCArray = doubleArray`? Would we be able to mutate `objCArray`, or would it give us a runtime error since we would be trying to change the value of the initial immutable array?

Comment: @halileohalilei Try it and see. (And look at the inferred type of `objCArray` when you do.)

Comment: So if anyone was wondering, I tried it and the second array is the **copy** of the first one in this case. The inferred type of the the second one is also the same as the first array.

Answer (score 2):

This is valid because `var` just means that you can assign something else to it later as Martin says in the comments.  `NSArray` is an immutable object.  In the Foundation Swift module for `NSArray`, `subscript` is marked as `get` only:

```
extension NSArray {

    // ...

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    open subscript(idx: Int) -> Any { get }

    // ...
}
```

As for why is the bridging legal, see this note in the Swift Array module:

> ```
> /// Bridging Between Array and NSArray
> /// ==================================
> ///
> /// When you need to access APIs that expect data in an `NSArray` instance
> /// instead of `Array`, use the type-cast operator (`as`) to bridge your
> /// instance. For bridging to be possible, the `Element` type of your array
> /// must be a class, an `@objc` protocol (a protocol imported from Objective-C
> /// or marked with the `@objc` attribute), or a type that bridges to a
> /// Foundation type.
> ///
> /// The following example shows how you can bridge an `Array` instance to
> /// `NSArray` to use the `write(to:atomically:)` method. In this example, the
> /// `colors` array can be bridged to `NSArray` because its `String` elements
> /// bridge to `NSString`. The compiler prevents bridging the `moreColors`
> /// array, on the other hand, because its `Element` type is
> /// `Optional<String>`, which does *not* bridge to a Foundation type.
> ///
> ///     let colors = ["periwinkle", "rose", "moss"]
> ///     let moreColors: [String?] = ["ochre", "pine"]
> ///
> ///     let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "names.plist")
> ///     (colors as NSArray).write(to: url, atomically: true)
> ///     // true
> ///
> ///     (moreColors as NSArray).write(to: url, atomically: true)
> ///     // error: cannot convert value of type '[String?]' to type 'NSArray'
> ///
> /// Bridging from `Array` to `NSArray` takes O(1) time and O(1) space if the
> /// array's elements are already instances of a class or an `@objc` protocol;
> /// otherwise, it takes O(*n*) time and space.
> ///
> /// Bridging from `NSArray` to `Array` first calls the `copy(with:)`
> /// (`- copyWithZone:` in Objective-C) method on the array to get an immutable
> /// copy and then performs additional Swift bookkeeping work that takes O(1)
> /// time. For instances of `NSArray` that are already immutable, `copy(with:)`
> /// usually returns the same array in O(1) time; otherwise, the copying
> /// performance is unspecified. The instances of `NSArray` and `Array` share
> /// storage using the same copy-on-write optimization that is used when two
> /// instances of `Array` share storage.
> ///
> /// - Note: The `ContiguousArray` and `ArraySlice` types are not bridged;
> ///   instances of those types always have a contiguous block of memory as
> ///   their storage.
> /// - SeeAlso: `ContiguousArray`, `ArraySlice`, `Sequence`, `Collection`,
> ///   `RangeReplaceableCollection`
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` is an immutable object.  There is a subclass of `NSArray` called `NSMutableArray` that will allow you to modify the objects it contains.  If you change your code to `var objCArray = doubleArray as NSMutableArray` you will be able to do what you're asking.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "Why is the line `var objCArray = doubleArray as NSArray` legal?"

Comment: @JAL it doesn't answer the direct question "why is it legal", but it does answer the underlying question "why do I get an error when I say `objCArray[0] = 2`".

Comment: Well technically the answer to that is the `subscript` for `NSArray` is `get` only, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The type cast is legal because the Swift immutable array (doubleArray) is compatible with NSArray through automatic (toll-free) bridging.   So your assignment to objCArray gives you a mutable reference to an underlying valued type (that is immutable).

From then on, the objCArray is treated as a reference type.

This means that you can perform any methods that the object type (NSArray) will allow and assign a new object instance to the variable (objCArray).

In this case, the NSArray class is designed to manipulate immutable arrays so it will not let you assign values to subscript. The compiler detects this based on NSArray's implementation of subscripts, not based on the mutability of the variable that references the NSArray object.

This is one of the differences between referenced types (NSArray) and valued types (Swift Array) and it works as intended.  Swift's "let", when applied to valued types prevents any modification of the variable's content.  Using "let" for referenced types prevents changing the reference variable, but lets you modify the content of the referenced object.